# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a point to be an interior point of a parabola?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Point M is called an interior point of the given parabola if any line passing through the M point (not parallel to the parabola axis) intersects this parabola at two different points. What is the necessary and sufficient condition for the point (X<sub>0</sub>, Y<sub>0</sub>) to be an interior point of a parabola $y^2 = 2px $?

Comment: Draw a picture. Then think about replacing the $=$ sign in the equation with an inequality.

Comment: The way it reads, it has to be that any arbitrary line (other than one parallel to the axis of symmetry) must intersect the parabola twice; Not just that there exists some line through the point that intersects the parabola twice. Draw a parabola out and label a point outside it, you'll see that there is some line that can be drawn which either does not intersect the parabola, or intersects it once or twice. A point inside the parabola you cannot find a line which does not intersect it twice.

Comment: @EthanBolker’s hint is spot on. If you don’t want to do that, then you might try working with an equivalent condition: the polar of the point has _no_ intersections with the parabola.

Comment: @amd I agree with you that thinking in terms of polars would simplify the issue. But the asker wants a condition in terms of "all lines through $(x_0,y_0)$ intersect the parabola".

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the parabola with equation $y^2=2px$.

Let $M(x_0,y_0)$ with $x_0 \neq 0$ (the summit is a particular case).

The general equation of a line passing through $M$ is

$$(L_m) : \ \ \ y=y_0+m(x-x_0)\tag{0}$$

Thus, the abscissas of the intersection points of line $L_m$ with parabola $P$ are such that :

$$(y_0+m(x-x_0))^2=2px$$

an equation that we can reorder as a quadratic in variable $x$:

$$
m^2x^2 + 2(- m^2x_0 + my_0 - p)x+ (mx_0 - y_0)^2 = 0
 $$

with discriminant

$$\Delta=4(- m^2x_0 + my_0 - p)^2-4(m(mx_0 - y_0))^2 $$

Taking into account the form $4(A^2-B^2)=4(A+B)(A-B)$ of $\Delta$, we get the simplified form :

$$\Delta=4p(2m^2x_0+2my_0+p)\tag{1}$$

Now, taking your definition, point $M$ is interior to parabola $P$ if, whatever $m$, there are two (real !) roots in (1), which is expressed by condition :

$$\forall m, \ \ \Delta>0\tag{2}$$

Due to the fact that the coefficient of $m^2$ in (1) is $>0$, condition (2) is ensured if equation

$$\Delta=0 \ \iff \ 2x_0m^2+2y_0m+p=0,\tag{3}$$

considered as a quadratic in $m$, has no real roots.

This is equivalent to the fact that the discriminant $\delta$ of (3) :

$$\delta=4y_0^2-8px_0=4(y_0^2-2px_0)$$

is negative, whence the necessary and sufficient condition :

> $$y_0^2<2px_0$$

of "insideness" as could be awaited.

Comment: A minor quibble: your “general” equation omits one of the lines through $M$.

Comment: @amd you are perfectly right. Either one accepts $m=\infty$ or one treats apart the particular case of vertical lines (which, besides, correspond to double roots...).